# laravel 8 laravel-dompdf 0.9.0 Image not found or type unknown

Tags: php, laravel, image, pdf, dompdf

I am trying to place an image in pdf but it shows an error: 'Image not found or type unknown'

Code in the controller:

```
public function generatePDF(Report $report){
 $date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
 $pdf = PDF::loadView('frontend.agencies.reportPDF', compact('report'));
 return $pdf->download('report - ' . $date . '.pdf');
}
```

In the view:

```
...
<img src="{{ asset('storage/reports/' . $report->id . '/' . $report->image) }}"
                style="width: 200px; height: 200px">
```

I have proved the src of the image and it is correct, it shows the image, but it is not working in the pdf.

Could you help me, please?

Comment: Try using the path to the file at operating system level instead of through the url. Ie: `src="{{ storage_path('app/public/reports/' . $report->id . '/' . $report->image) }}"`

Comment: Thank you but it is not working